# loadView of UIViewController not called

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to setup a UIViewController within a NavigationController programmatically, however the loadView nor viewDidLoad method get called.

This is my code in the app delegate:

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:window.frame];
viewController.view = view;

UINavgationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[window addSubview:[navController view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When I start the app I see a navigationbar, but no calls to loadView. What am I missing?
I thought loadView gets called after you call `view`

**Edit**

```
MyViewController *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
[viewController view];  // doesn't look right?

UINavgationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];

[window addSubview:[navController view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

edited towards Jonah's comment, but loadView still doesn't get called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `UIViewController` will create its view (by loading it from a nib or implementing `-loadView`) when the controller's `view` getter is called and its view is currently `nil`.

In the code shown you never invoke the view property's getter, only its setter.

Also, you are assigning the controller's view from your app delegate. `UIViewController`s are expected to create their own views on demand, not have them provided by some other class. This approach will cause you problems later when you realize that the controller unloads its view and attempts to recreate it in response to memory warnings. Let your controller create its view, don't try to pass it one.

Comment: Regarding your second remark, assigning the view, you mean my 2nd and 3rd line of code, right? That makes sense.  But how would I call the getter in this case?

Comment: `[viewController view]` invokes the view's getter but there should be no need for you to do so directly. The `UINavigationController` you added your view controller to will call that getter at some point in order to add your controller's view to the view hierarchy. Can you share your view controller implementation? It sounds like you have something else going on.

Comment: It's basically the empty UIViewController template from Xcode, but no (view) method gets called besides init. There I tried to setup a view like this: - (id) init{
 self((self = [super init])){
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 self.view = view;
 [view release];
 }
return self;
}

Comment: If you're setting your controller's view outside of `-loadView` then you're not following the contract for a UIViewController and shouldn't expect `-loadView` to be called (since the controller already has a view) or `-viewDidLoad`(since the view did not need to be loaded). You should only be assigning a UIViewController's view property within `'loadView`.

Comment: I was trying `-init` as a last resort, since loadView wasn't called in the first place. So if I delete the setup part in init again, `-loadView` or `-viewDidLoad` won't get called either. I really appreciate your help.  @jonah

Comment: Ok I noticed something. If I don't use a navigationController and add the ViewControllers view to the window both methods get called. So the NavigationController doesn't seem to access the view of the rootViewController in my example.

Comment: My problem was I released the navcontroller too earl, thanks for keeping up with me

Answer (score 2):

maybe you were not facing this issue... but the other day I ran into the same irritating trouble.. loadView, viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear not being called in my UIViewController.

My issue was v. simple but bit tricky to catch if you are not very careful. Instead of writing

```
-(void) loadView
```

I wrote:

```
-(void) loadview
```

Please note that this won't fire any warning. The difference of "V" and "v" in loadView can easily be missed. And obviously, since loadView didn't get called, viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear won't get called either as there was no view that got loaded (am not using any nib..creating the view programmatically).

-Anshu

Answer (score 2):

Another gotcha worth noting is if you define a

```
@synthesize view;
```

without a matching @property in your implementation, this can result in calls to your view controller's returning nil, and no call to your loadView method.

Comment: Aha!  This one got me.  I ended up with a "@synthesize view" in a class due to an overzealous find/replace operation, didn't realize it, and all of a sudden my view was entirely blank because loadView never got called any more.  This was tricky to track down.  Thanks!